# acclimating new hardwood, southwestern Ontario, during the winter

Tags: flooring, hardwood

first time question in this forum.

I am expecting delivery of new hickory hardwood flooring in the next few weeks. I've been doing a lot of reading about acclimation. General guidelines specify acclimation in a 30-50% RH environment in the house. More specific guidelines from the NWFA recommend shooting for the wood having a moisture content around halfway between the local typical minimum and maximum indoor wood moisture content for the area. Checking the NWFA installation guide, that range is 7-11% for my area, so I assume I should be shooting for 9% wood moisture? I do have an accurate species-specific wood moisture meter so I can check.

I want to avoid the problem of installing when it is on the dry side, then having cupping/buckling problems when it gets humid in the summer. Taking all this information into consideration, since we are in an area that gets quite humid, and installation will occur during the dry winter, I have concluded that I should probably get the humidity level in my house up as close to 50% as I can, so when the wood arrives it can acclimate properly and attain as close as possible to the 9% target moisture in the wood. I turned up the humidifier to 45% (max), previously the house was at about 35%. With the house at 45%RH I'm hoping the wood will stabilize at 8-9% moisture as per the chart in the NWFA installation guide.

I do realize that there will be slight gaps forming between boards if the house drops to 30% in the future during the winter but I'd rather have that than cupping/buckling risk in the summer.  Any comments on my approach? Am I missing anything?  I am probably too obsessive about this, lol.

(note: moisture will be controlled after installation with a humidifier in winter and AC in summer).

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here in the next 24 hours or so, you might post a comment asking a mod to migrate the question to the [woodworking.se] sister site. Loads of experience over there. Please don't cross-post, though, or if you do repost there, please delete this one.

Comment: In the restoration shop, our rule of thumb is "an inch a year" counting entry from both sides if not varnished. So 3/4" stock needs 3/8 of a year.

Comment: Could a mod please migrate this question to the woodworking site?  thanks